# Can't upgrade ESXI from 6.0 to 6.7

Tags: vmware-esxi

(Sorry for bad english)
I'm attempting to use esxcli to upgrade my host from ESXI 6.0 to 6.7 because of some added features. Whenever I run

`esxcli software profile update -d https://hostupdate.vmware.com/software/VUM/PRODUCTION/main/vmw-depot-index.xml -p ESXi-6.7.0-8169922-standard`

`[DependencyError]
 VIB VFrontDe_bootbank_net51-r8169_6.011.00-2vft.510.0.0.799733 requires vmkapi_ 2_1_0_0, but the requirement cannot be satisfied within the ImageProfile.
 VIB VFrontDe_bootbank_net51-sky2_1.20-2vft.510.0.0.799733 requires vmkapi_2_1_0 _0, but the requirement cannot be satisfied within the ImageProfile.
 Please refer to the log file for more details.`

EDIT: After attempting to upgrade to 6.5 first, as suggested by the first comment, running this command `esxcli software profile update -d https://hostupdate.vmware.com/software/VUM/PRODUCTION/main/vmw-depot-index.xml -p ESXi-6.5.0-20180502001-standard`

I get a different error: `[InstallationError]
 [Errno 28] No space left on device
       vibs = VMware_locker_tools-light_6.5.0-1.47.8285314
 Please refer to the log file for more details.`

Comment: Try to uograde to 6.5, after to 6.7

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So upon further research, I had to install the VIB that was causing problems manually, then go through with the upgrade to 6.5. Now upon rebooting, YAY I'm at 6.5. I'll link to where I found the answer.
[experts-exchange](https://www.experts-exchange.com/posts/4474/Andy's-VMware-vSphere-tip-6-InstallationError-Errno-28.html)

Comment: If this answer solves your request, you can mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: And please add the essential parts from that link to your answer. The answer becomes useless if that link goes dead some day.